# Rename screencapture program

Tags: command-line, screen-capture

I would like to rename the "screencapture" utility triggered with the shift+cmd+3 keys, in order to take screenshots from a program that recognizes and disables this utility.

Specifically, I want a different name to appear under `ps` when that utility is running.

Is there a way to rename or alias this utility system-wide?

Comment: What do you mean by "rename?"

Comment: Change the name of the process as it would appear in `ps`

Comment: Okay, the question is clear, but I don't see the logic. Why would you need to rename the process in order for another program to implement it? What program?

Comment: I have a program that blocks screenshots, and it uses the name "screencapture" to detect the utility. I want to bypass that.

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7458145/2384224) from Stackoverflow. I'm writing this as a comment as opposed to an answer because I don't want to test it/I'm not quite sure how to implement it/I can't add anything of value to supplement it.

Comment: Why not just use another program to make screen caps? I really don't think you are going to be able to rename a process without a kernel extension.  If you had the ability to install kernel extensions you'd have the ability to remove the program that is troubling you.

Comment: I don't get your intentions. Do you have a program that disable `screencapture` ? Or do you want to make one ? Disabling `screencapture` is something that you want to achieve ? Or something that you want to stop ?

Comment: What kind of broken program do you have ? If I were you, I would rather try to fix this program, or to replace it, or to circumvent its blocking. For this last option, I can advise you. A program must not block you from taking screen photos. And you don't have to risk breaking your system because of such program. Mac OS X is very sensitive to his native names now. Fiddling with them is generally ill-advised.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible to replace the program. @YoshiBotX's answer works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is not that easy, but it is possible.
When calling

> which screencapture

I get

> /usr/sbin/screencapture

I enter sudo mode and cd to /usr/sbin

> sudo su 
>   cd /usr/sbin

I rename the screencapure programm :

> mv screencapture capturescreen

And after that, I create a symlink to the old one:

> ln -s capturescreen screencapture

now when calling capturescreen, It is called capturescreen.
But when doing CMD+Shift+3, I get the screencapture process.

But You could fix that with creating a Service in Automator and create a Shell-Script-Action, simply calling "capturescreen ~/Desktop/Output.png"

And after that in the System-Preferences, Assign a Shortcut to the Service.

But you could also simply call Terminal and enter "capturescreen ~/Desktop/Output.png"

Even further, you can modify the screencapture action in automator to get the timestamp back and use it as the main tool for schooting screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

Tho you said "rename" I'm thinking you mean "remap".  You want to be able to use shift+cmd+3 to trigger a different app to take screenshots...

This can be managed in the Keyboard System Preference.

You can change the current key combination for snapshots and add your own shortcuts for other Apps.

See screenshot from 10.9.3

[image]

Comment: No, I want to change _the name of the process_.

Comment: He does not want to remap it, he wants to have a different process name when calling ps in temrinal